# Get contact names with email address

Tags: android, contacts

here is my code :

```
Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
      String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
      name1.add(name);
    }
    phones.close();
```

i want to do is to display only those contacts name with email address and if they dont have they shouldn't be displayed at all. im wondering how could i do that.

Comment: Have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205999/android-get-a-cursor-only-with-contacts-that-have-an-email-listed-android-2-0

Comment: Please try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258984/get-contacts-with-email-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA
};

...

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    try {
        final int contactIdIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID);
        final int displayNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        final int emailIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);
        long contactId;
        String displayName, address;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            contactId = cursor.getLong(contactIdIndex);
            displayName = cursor.getString(displayNameIndex);
            address = cursor.getString(emailIndex);
            ...
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```