# How to get only those contacts which do have email-id associated with it?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I need to get only those contacts which do have email-id associated with it.
I need to get all details for above contacts.
I did a hard R&D over internet but didn't get any luck.
Please don't make it duplicate.

I got following link:

[Get contacts with email id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258984/get-contacts-with-email-id)

[How to get contact email id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152442/how-to-get-contact-email-id)

But Couldn't get any help.

Please Help!

Comment: Why exactly were those two links of no help?

Comment: @IshitaSinha as I mentioned I need to get only those contacts which have email-id, both above links are for getting all contacts and retrieve their email-id, I hope you got it now.

Comment: Check if the code in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117049/get-only-email-address-from-contact-list-android) helps?

Comment: @IshitaSinha Earlier I tried this as well however as I mentioned I need all information (ie name, phone no, address etc) related to that contact which is associated with email-id. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I thought you needed to be pointed in the right direction, not code. You could parse a raw query with `"SELECT * FROM " + ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI + " WHERE " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS + "IS NOT NULL"` in combination with the suggestions in those questions.

Comment: @IshitaSinha the following query will throw 'no such column' exception "SELECT * FROM " + ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI + " WHERE " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS + "IS NOT NULL" as ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS is not belongs to Data table. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA` instead of `ADDRESS`?